# How can I change legend labels in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change `Control` to `0%Shade` in a ggplot legend. Any advice on how to do this without it disagreeing with all other plot settings?

[image: Predictive Plot]

```
pred_plot <- ggplot(pred, aes(x, predicted, color=group, fill=group)) +
  geom_line() + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), alpha = 0.1, colour=NA) +
  labs(x = 'Ambient Temp (C)', y = "Predicted Deer Use") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(pred$x), max(pred$x), by = 5),1), labels=scales::label_number(accuracy = 1)) + 
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=30, colour='black'),axis.title=element_text(size=30,face="bold")) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.box = "horizontal", legend.title = element_blank(), legend.key = element_blank(),
        legend.key.size = unit(4, 'cm'),legend.text = element_text(size=20)) + 
  transition_reveal(x)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [renaming variable names in a ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52656493/renaming-variable-names-in-a-ggplot2)

Comment: The easiest way to to change the value in your data. Otherwise you can specify `labels` in both `scale_fill_manual()` and `scale_color_manual()` (since this is a combined fill and color scale).

Comment: Any attempts I have made resulted in the addition of new labels instead of replacing the current labels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that via the `labels=` argument in a `scale_color_*()` function by supplying a named vector.  Here's an example:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1235)
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10, z = sample(c("Control", "B", "C"), size=10, replace=TRUE))

df$z <- factor(df$z, levels=c("Control", "B", "C"))  # setting level order

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y, color=z)) + geom_point(size=4)
p
```

[image]

To change the name of "Control" totally "in plot code", I'll use `scale_color_hue(labels=...)`.  Note that by default, `ggplot2` uses an evenly-spaced hue scaling, so this keeps the colors themselves the same.  Using a named vector is not required, but a good idea to ensure you don't have mixing up of names/labels:

```
p + scale_color_hue(labels=c("Control" = "A", "B"="B", "C"="C"))
```

[image]

Comment: ```scale_color_hue``` added new labels instead of replacing the 3 I had. I now have 6 labels.

Comment: @JLD475 that's because you have both a fill scale and a color scale. Use `scale_fill_hue` as well as `scale_color_hue` if you want the same legend. You might need to give them both the same `name = ` as well to merge them